# how to write an opencv function that take one image as paramater and returns 2 images

Tags: opencv, iplimage, mat

i wanna build an opencv function that takes one IplImage image as parameter and returns 2 IplImage images. is this doable in opencv (c++). I prefer if it's using IplImage but i will appreciate other options

Comment: do not know about opencv but in java would return a array or set element, with the first 2 elements set as the return images.

Comment: yea i expect that but I'm new in opencv and it has a different syntax so i wan't able to do it

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Take two "output" arguments by reference, or return an `std::pair<cv::Mat, cv::Mat>`. You should probably prefer `cv::Mat` to `IplImage` unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: actually my reason is that i have no time to learn cvmat while i know some iplimge. but i'm trying ...anyway thank u,, my problem has been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return several images by [passing them by reference as function arguments](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/). Example:

```
void myFunction(const cv::Mat& input_image, cv::Mat &output1, cv::Mat &output2) {
    // modify output1
    input_image.copyTo(output1);
    rectangle(output1, cv::Rect(10,10,100,100), cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 2);

    // modify output2
    cvtColor(input_image,output2,CV_RGB2GRAY); 
}

int main() {
    cv::Mat input_image = imread("sample.jpg");
    cv::Mat out1, out2;

    myFunction(input_image, out1, out2);

    // now out1 and out2 are modified by myFunction
}
```

Example is for cv::Mat but you can do the same with IplImage. You should use cv::Mat instead of IplImage.